# Recreating a mac-like drop down: what type of gradient to use for "glint" appearance?

Tags: html, css

This is primarily a visual design question.

I'm trying to create a drop-down option menu similar to the mac menu in css, something like these:

[image: mac drop down menu]

You can see a simplified version of what I currently have accomplished [here on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLu7z/1/).

I've made the main drop down transparent and removed the arrow (to be re-added in `#rightTab` with css triangles):

```
background: transparent;
background-image: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

and now I'm trying to create a gradient that looks similar to the "glint" on the mac drop-downs. I'm using [this gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). However, my initial assumption that this effect could be created with a fade-in/fade-out of an off-white silver was wrong. It looks very flat and dull.

So any ideas on how to create an effect similar to the macs?

Comment: I would suggest taking a screen shot of the Mac slider that you wish to recreate, use Photoshop to get the correct colors and placements, then use that info on the generator.  Give me a minute and I can see what I come up with.

Comment: Top border is lighter.
Bottom border is darker.
The glare flares up at the ends, which can be accomplished with an additional radial gradient, but they will not work in IE.
You'd almost be better using a canvas element.

Comment: @JohnManly I'm pretty bad with Photoshop, but that's a good idea. I was hoping just for a general idea of what this entails. Thanks.

Comment: @circusdei I don't necessarily want _exactly_ the mac appearance, just something similar.

Comment: The method is called Trompe-l'œil (Trick of the Eye).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I just came up with, but when I went to copy, I noticed they have an "Upload Image" option.  Try to upload an image of the gradient that you wish to copy.

```
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e9e9e9 49%, #e0e0e0 51%, #ededed 52%, #f0f0f0 95%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(49%,#e9e9e9), color-stop(51%,#e0e0e0), color-stop(52%,#ededed), color-stop(95%,#f0f0f0), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 49%,#e0e0e0 51%,#ededed 52%,#f0f0f0 95%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 49%,#e0e0e0 51%,#ededed 52%,#f0f0f0 95%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 49%,#e0e0e0 51%,#ededed 52%,#f0f0f0 95%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 49%,#e0e0e0 51%,#ededed 52%,#f0f0f0 95%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

I would offer more assistance, but it's time for me to clock out and go home!

I also only concentrated on the gradient, you will still have some `border` and `box-shadow` work to do.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a lot of work to get it to look right.

[image: OSX Select Box shading]